# Detect bluetooth SPP disconnection without using packets

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth

I have some Bluetooth devices which connect to an Android phone, however I'm having trouble detecting disconnections. The bluetooth devices don't send data packets unless they need to, so it's not an option to use a watchdog on packet reception to detect a disconnect. I've read that you can use the ACLDisconnected broadcast, but this event is never firing for me (I've waited minutes). What is a reliable way to detect a disconnection in Android 6?

Here is my AclDisconnect registering code:

```
_filter = new IntentFilter();
_filter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound);
_filter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionBondStateChanged);
_filter.AddAction(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted);
_filter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected);
_filter.AddAction(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested);
context.RegisterReceiver(_bluetoothDeviceReceiver, _filter);
```

And the callback (which doesn't fire on disconnect)

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    string action = intent.Action;

    if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected || action == BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnectRequested)
    {
         Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Disconnected, null, null)?.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a callback for BluetoothGattCallback?

Comment: Bluetooth Gatt is low energy related. SPP stands for Serial Port Protocol, which is part of Bluetooth Classic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Xamarin, but in plain Android / Java this is typically done by catching the `IOException` that is thrown by the InputStream when the stream is closed. For example:

```
// In your listening thread
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
while (true) {
    try {
        int nextByte = inputStream.read();
        // Do something with it
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Here you know that you are disconnected
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in Xamarin. I'll add that from my testing this is the only way to do it. You must obtain the Stream object from the BluetoothSocket via __stream = _socket.InputStream as InputStreamInvoker;_

Answer (score 0):

BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected is indeed unreliable and the only sure way to detect a disconnection is to catch an IOException, like the previous answer states.

So for this you would have to develop a "ping" mechanism where data is sent every X time.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to receive any data, you can just block on the read() call until a disconnection occurs.